# R merge pdf into one pdf

Tags: r, pdf, merge

I have a folder which contains around 400 .pdf files, each .pdf file is 2 pages total.

All .pdf file names are under the following format:

```
148-c16631-27-02-2018.pdf
```

What I would like is to merge under one pdf file, the pdf files that have a certain code in the file name in `R`. For instance:

```
148-c16631-27-02-2018.pdf
148-c14369-27-02-2018.pdf
148-c101593-27-02-2018.pdf
```

These have the code 148 which is unique, to be merged into 1 pdf file with 8 pages.

Thank you in advance for any input.

Comment: Try the [`staplr`](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/staplr/index.html) package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) and ensure it is on your path (or if not on your path use the full pathname when referring to it in the `system` command below).  Then run the code below.  No packages are used.

```
setwd("...directory where pdf files are located...") ##
infiles <- Sys.glob("148-*.pdf") ##
outfile <- "148.pdf" ##
system(paste("pdftk", paste(infiles, collapse = " "), "cat output", outfile))
```

There are some packages that provide wrappers around pdftk:

- the staplr package. Unfortunately, it is probably not too useful here because it does not allow specification of the files or their order in the output -- one can only specify the input and output directories.  ** Update ** The current version of staplr now allows specification of the files as mentioned in the comments.
- the animation package. The `pdftk` command that this package provides is a slightly simpler alternative than using `system` with `pdftk` directly.  For concatenating it would be the following where we assume that the 3 lines marked ## above have already been run.

  ```
  library(animation)
  ani.options(pdftk = "/path/to/pdftk") # or if on path: ani.options(pdftk = "pdftk")
  pdftk(infiles, "cat", outfile, "")
  ```

  This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982408/how-to-find-byte-sizes-of-r-figures-on-pages/41294644#41294644) has an example of using the animation package with pdftk to burst pages.

Comment: Note that current version of staplr does allow specifying individual files

Comment: I might be a little brain dead today but can't see it

Comment: "current version of staplr **does** allow specifying individual files" (see [staple_pdf documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/staplr/versions/2.9.0/topics/staple_pdf))

Comment: (It might be useful/necessary to use `shQuote(infiles)` (or `sQuote(infiles,FALSE)`) if any filenames have spaces.)