# Is there a way to specify portrait/landscape orientation per page using pdf()?

Tags: r, pdf-generation

I am trying to find a way to set the rotation per page. For example, this is the trimmed down code I am using:

```
  pdf('test.pdf', 
      paper='USr', width=90, height=12, onefile=TRUE)
  grid.draw(grobtable1)
  grid.draw(ggplot1)
  grid.newpage()
  grid.draw(grobtable2)
  grid.draw(ggplot2)
  grid.newpage()
  grid.draw(table.portrait)
  dev.off()
```

I would like all the pages except for the last one to be portrait. Is there any elegant way to do this using pdf()?

I have no experience with R Markdown yet, as I have read that might be a way to do what I desire. However, the code that I gave is something I use as a function, of which the plots and tables are being called from another function output. Hence, I thought using R Markdown would require me to make new Markdown files all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can alter the pdf orientation in the middle of a run.  You could write out to two files and merge them together using the `staplr` package.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49009727/r-merge-pdf-into-one-pdf).

Comment: After some critical thinking, this way is perhaps more efficient since I need to have the same last page every time I merge. Thank you!